# Spark session configured is not utilizing the complete resources.Please suggest what changes need to be applied

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is my cluster capacity:
Min Resources: memory:2400000, vCores:375, disks:32.0
Max Resources: memory:4800000, vCores:800, disks:64.0

I am using pyspark to convert 4TB of textformat data to parquet format. Spark session configured is as below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn")\
    .appName("hstflprqt")\
    .config("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "1024G")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "768G")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "512")\
    .config("spark.num.executors", "256")\
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "256")\
    .config("spark.queue", "myqueue")\
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")\
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Spark is utilizing only Resources: memory:15360, vCores:7, disks:0.14

Comment: Can you please post the `spark-submit` command you use, along with any arguments?

Comment: as i declared all required parameters in session config, i directly call spark-submit pyfile.py

Comment: My team and I had also faced an under-utilization issue, using mesos though. I would suggest to check whether the cluster has indeed the capacity you mention and that the resources are available to the worker machines, that yarn sees the same resources, and that all are in the same network, but first try submitting the job with command line configurations with different values for `spark.executor.memory` for example and see if anything changes. E.g. try `spark-submit --conf spark.executor.cores=2 main.py` etc. If not, check cluster resources and configuration.

Comment: Come to think about it, can you please post the output of `print(spark.sparkContext.getConf())` and `print(spark.conf)`?

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in spark-submit, as of now it will only take minimum default resources available in your setup convert your application to jar and run in spark-submit like

```
spark-submit --class "Spark.DVT" --master yarn --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 5 application.jar
```

In spark-submit you can specify how much resource it can take